# Connectedness of cones in the boundary of a 1-ended hyperbolic group

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a one-ended hyperbolic group.  We can think of the boundary of $G$ as consisting of geodesic rays originating at the identity in some Cayley graph, modulo the relationship of being asymptotic.

Let $g\in G$. By the cone over $g$, we mean the subset of the boundary given by geodesic rays emanating from 1 which pass through $g$.  (Presumably, this depends on our choice of Cayley graph.)

Is there some Cayley graph of $G$ such that for every $g\in G$, the cone over $g$ is connected?

Comment: @YCor: I think you are misinterpreting the question.  As stated, the cone over $g$ consists of the endpoints of geodesic rays that start at $1$ and pass through $g$.  It is true that there is a geodesic connecting $g$ to any point in the boundary, but that geodesic need not be a subset of a geodesic starting at $1$.  For instance, in a free group $F(S)$, if you identify the boundary with infinite reduced words (these are geodesic rays starting at $1$), the cone over a reduced word $w$ consists of infinite reduced words that start with $w$.

Comment: I think it's more usual to call subsets like these 'shadows'. At least, Danny Calegari does in his survey paper on ergodic theory.